# Pandas: Conditionally generate descriptions from column content

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to iron out some issues with a function that uses `pandas regex` via `str.extract` to get each row in column `"name"` to generate column `"description"`. I am using `regex` and not `split` since the code must be able to manage a variety of formattings.

The function must be modified to acknowledge various conditions.

DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(["LONG AXP UN X3 VON", "SHORT BIDU UN 5x VON", "SHORT GOOG VON", "LONG GOOG VON"], columns=["name"])
```

Input:

```
name
"LONG AXP UN X3 VON"
"SHORT BIDU UN 5x VON"
"SHORT GOOG VON"
"LONG GOOG VON"
```

Current code:

```
description_map = {"AXP":"American Express", "BIDU":"Baidu"}
sign_map = {"LONG": "", "SHORT": "-"}
def f(strseries):
    stock = strseries.str.extract(r"\s(\S+)\s").map(description_map)
    leverage = strseries.str.extract(r"(X\d+|\d+X)\s", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    sign = strseries.str.extract(r"(\S+)\s").map(sign_map)
    return "Tracks " + stock + " with " + sign + leverage + " leverage"

df["description"] = f(df["name"])
```

Current output:

```
name                        description
"LONG AXP UN X3 VON"        "Tracks American Express with X3 leverage"
"SHORT BIDU UN 5x VON"      "Tracks Baidu with -5x leverage"
"SHORT GOOG VON"            ""
"LONG GOOG VON"             ""
```

---

Desired output:

```
name                        description
"LONG AXP UN X3 VON"        "Tracks American Express with 3x leverage"
"SHORT BIDU UN 5x VON"      "Tracks Baidu inversely with -5x leverage"
"SHORT GOOG VON"            "Tracks inversely"
"LONG GOOG VON"             "Tracks"
```

Implications:

- If `sign` is `"-"`, how can I make it add `direction = "inversely"` into the string?
- If no `stock` is matched in `name` with dictionary `description_map`: set `stock = ""` and return the string.
- If no `leverage` is found in `name`: ignore the part `"with" + sign + leverage + " leverage"`.
- Split and reorder the `sign + leverage` so that it always displays in the order `-5x"` regardless of if it was inputted as `"SHORT X5"`.

Comment: did the below solution work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent some time writing this function:

```
description_map = {"AXP":"American Express", "BIDU":"Baidu"}
sign_map = {"LONG": "", "SHORT": "-"}

stock_match = re.compile(r"\s(\S+)\s")
leverage_match = re.compile("[0-9]x|x[0-9]|X[0-9]|[0-9]X")

def f(value):

    f1 = lambda x: description_map[stock_match.findall(x)[0]] if stock_match.findall(x)[0] in description_map else ''
    f2 = lambda x: leverage_match.findall(x)[0] if len(leverage_match.findall(x)) > 0 else ''
    f3 = lambda x: '-' if 'SHORT' in x else ''

    stock = f1(value)
    leverage = f2(value)
    sign = f3(value)

    statement = "Tracks " + stock

    if stock == "":
        if sign == '-':
            return statement + "{}".format('inversely')
        else:
            return "Tracks"

    if leverage[0].replace('X','x') == 'x':
        leverage = leverage[1]+leverage[0].replace('X','x')

    if leverage != '' and sign == '-':
        statement += " {} with {}{} leverage".format('inversely', sign, leverage)
    elif leverage != '' and sign == '':
        statement += " with {} leverage".format(leverage)
    else:
        if sign == '-':
            statement += " {} ".format('Inversely')

    return statement

df["description"] = df["name"].map(lambda x:f(x))
```

Output:

```
In [97]: %paste
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(["LONG AXP UN X3 VON", "SHORT BIDU UN 5x VON", "SHORT GOOG VON", "LONG GOOG VON"], columns=["name"])

## -- End pasted text --

In [98]: df
Out[98]: 
                   name
0    LONG AXP UN X3 VON
1  SHORT BIDU UN 5x VON
2        SHORT GOOG VON
3         LONG GOOG VON

In [99]: df["description"] = df["name"].map(lambda x:f(x))

In [100]: df
Out[100]: 
                   name                               description
0    LONG AXP UN X3 VON  Tracks American Express with 3x leverage
1  SHORT BIDU UN 5x VON  Tracks Baidu inversely with -5x leverage
2        SHORT GOOG VON                          Tracks inversely
3         LONG GOOG VON                                    Tracks
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to develop this! I tried it as soon as I came online and it works perfectly. I have studied the code and it was very insightful for my current stage in learning. Thank you once again and I hope you gained some developmental return through your effort!